# Python /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Not a directory

Tags: python, linux, bash

I did a mistake. I installed Python 3 and then I did the following command in order to have the defaut version Python as Python3

```
sudo ln -fs /opt/Python-3.4.1/python /usr/bin/python
```

But I wanted to come back to the python2.7 and I did

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python2.7/python /usr/bin/python
```

Now, When I want to run a bash script with python inside, I have this following error:

> /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Not a directory

When I run this command:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/env
```

I have this result in red:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 12 13:37 /usr/bin/env ->
>   /usr/bin/python2.7/python

Indeed, when I go in this directory, I don't have the env executable anymore but a broken link.

I didn't find a solution on the internet.

Could you help me ? I begin to feel bad about my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script Do not link `env` to actual `python` version, this program has special purpose (see related Q)

Comment: Yes It was a mistake. I saw this post but how I can fix it ?

Comment: Messing with `/usr/bin` is an absolute no-no on basically every modern platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okey, I solved my issue by reinstalling this env file.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Then thanks to this post in [Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429730)
I know better how to switch between version and do not do the same mistake anymore.

Comment: Thank you thank you so muhch, I am not a geek in Unixoid systems and it took me almost a whole day to figure it out that somehow I have deleted this file and I had no clue that this is part of core utils of Ubuntu 20.04, you saved me a lot of time waste, it worked and now npm -v gives the version and it works, before I tried installing and removing using default repositories, then NVM and nothing worked until finally this. Great to learn something new every day.